# Docusign Rest API - Enable signHereTabs on specific document instead of all those present in the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

When i send multiple documents to Docusign, i would like the `signHereTabs` to not be applied to all documents.

For example, if i have `main.pdf` and `annex.pdf`, and both of them contain the anchorString `(SignatorySignature_1)`, i don't want it to be applied to `annex.pdf`.

My issue is that `annex.pdf` could have been signed previously : i don't want it to be signed a second time.

I see 2 solutions :

- display `annex.pdf` as a modal (but i prefer the inline view)
- use unique `anchorString` for each document (it's challenging in the current code base)

Is there a way to target a list of document for a tab, or disable all tabs from a specifique document ?

---

**Sample envelopeDefinition :**

```json
{
  "autoNavigation": true,
  "emailSubject": "xxxx",
  "allowComments": false,
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "xxx@xxx.xx",
        "name": "xx",
        "clientUserId": 1,
        "recipientId": 1,
        "routingOrder": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent",
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "main.pdf",
      "documentId": 1,
      "fileExtension": "pdf"
    },
    {
      "name": "annex.pdf",
      "documentId": 2,
      "fileExtension": "pdf"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Sample signHereTabs :**

```json
{
  signHereTabs: [
    {
      anchorString: `(SignatorySignature_1)`,
      anchorYOffset: -15,
      anchorXOffset: 0,
      anchorUnits: 'pixels',
      anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent: true,
      anchorMatchWholeWord: true,
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a back-end setting which controls whether, for the entire account, anchor text matching is per document or per envelope. Ask DocuSign customer service to change it to "per document" for you